# How to adjust Ext Panels side by side?

Tags: javascript, layout, extjs, window, panel

I know that there is a hbox layout. It accomodates all the panels in a horizontal line.

But I want the fact that if the panels exceed the container's width, they should be in the next row (like in normal HTML)

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be exactly like you're describing with the default layout. Do you have any sample code?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I was able to get this done is with the column layout, but you would have to nest the panels in containers.

Here is a fiddle:
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1oim

(toggle the placeholder.it width)